# Help? Cap on water line

Tags: water

My father is getting a new fridge that has no ice maker or anything etc. How do I cap the small water tube off so it stops leaking? [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the other end of that line, hardware stores sell caps (probably 3/8 inch) you can screw onto the fitting (probably an angle stop). If at all possible get a cap that has a rubber gasket in it.

If you cannot get to the other end, an overkill solution would be to attach a stop onto the valve and then leave the valve closed. (Risky though because someone may open the valve accidently - but you could cap the new valve just like I suggested in the first paragraph.)